# Issue with an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi there guys basically what I'm trying to do is this..

I've written this query..

```
SELECT * from comments where author = (select min(author ) from comments )
```

This is the result..

http://gyazo.com/87b7e11fd0b7acf9d4b7840ab67a36f1

But I am unsure if this query is correct

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely wrong. HINT: You want the author with MAXimum comments.

Comment: @shree.pat18 What have I done wrong? That's the user with the most comments

Comment: you have use `min(author)` to get the highest number of comments?

Comment: @RakeshShetty This is my table for comments, isn't James the highest commentor? http://gyazo.com/baee3c310c9fec4793ba22b98605b14e

Comment: @Ellie Do you understand what `min`/`max` do? `min(author)` would give you the author with the first name based on alphabetical order from the table. Now tell me, what do you think you have done wrong?

Comment: @shree.pat18 But in my DB James has the high comments, I would imagine this would be the new query..   SELECT * from comments where author = (select max(author ) from comments )

Comment: @Ellie author in your table is string and max/min will sort based on alphabetically which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

why you dont try this :

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) nr_coments
FROM comments 
GROUP BY author 
ORDER BY nr_coments DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: But James is the highest commenter in my DB.. http://gyazo.com/baee3c310c9fec4793ba22b98605b14e Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select username, first name, last name, count( username) from comments 
group by username, first name, last name
order by count(username)
```

this might help...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT
   Author,
   count(Comment)
FROM 
   table_name 
GROUP BY author 
ORDER BY 
   count(comment) 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```